# Obtener n caracteres de un string con swift

Tags: swift, swift3

Necesito obtener los 4 primeros caracteres de un string en Swift.

¿Hay alguna función para ello?

Comment: ¿Por qué está etiquetada como Swift2 **Y** Swift3?

Comment: Para que los que sigan swift 2 o swift 3 lo pudan ver si no siguen las otras etiquetas @Mariano

Comment: ¿En qué versión estás programando?

Comment: En la swift3 @Mariano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma más simple es la siguiente:

```
var str = "Obtener n caracteres de un string con swift"

let index: String.Index = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
var result: String = str.substring(to: index)
```

Answer (score 0):

aqui te va una extension de string que también te puede venir bien

```
extension String {
    func subString(startIndex: Int, length: Int) -> String {

       //primero compruebo que tengo mas elementos del que me quiero posicionar
       if startIndex > self.characters.count{
        return self
       }
       let start = self.startIndex.advancedBy(startIndex)
       //he de comprobar que no quiera un rango mayor al que existe
       var end : Index = start
       if (startIndex + length) <= self.characters.count {
           end = self.startIndex.advancedBy(startIndex + length)
       } else {
           //me piden hasta la posicion x y no hay tantos caracteres. Devuelvo hasta el final de la cadena
           end = self.startIndex.advancedBy(self.characters.count)
       }

       let r = start ..< end
       return self.substringWithRange(r)
   }
}
```